# I am trying to read TID of RFID tag from Chafon CF-RU 5102 in python, i am getting EPC rather than TID

Tags: python-3.x, rfid

i am following this link, https://github.com/wabson/chafon-rfid, and getting EPC not TID which is a universally unique Tag ID.

i am getting 000000000000000000000000 as EPC, whereas  E280F336200060000065DDBE is some what expected to be read

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: get_inventory_uhf = ReaderCommand(G2_TAG_INVENTORY)
transport = SerialTransport(device='COM3')
transport.write(get_inventory_uhf.serialize())
inventory_status = None
while inventory_status is None or inventory_status == G2_TAG_INVENTORY_STATUS_MORE_FRAMES:
    g2_response = G2InventoryResponseFrame18(transport.read_frame())
    inventory_status = g2_response.result_status
    for tag in g2_response.get_tag():
        EPC = tag.epc.hex().upper()
        print(EPC)          This is the code which i have been using

Comment: i trying to read TID from RFID using CF-RU 5102 mtag reader, whereas i am able to read tag's EPC

Answer (score 0):

```
EPC = tag.epc.hex().upper() print(EPC)
```

You are requesting information from the EPC mem bank. I don't know the exact API/SDK you  are using but maybe it contains more exposed methods to the RETU mem banks. Look at your tag object and see what methods are exposed to access the RETU mem bank.
For instance maybe you can get

```
  tag.id, tag.user or tag.reserve
```